# Change size of rename file field in Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

Is it possible to change width or height of rename file field in Nautilus? It is too small for me.

[This field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zywKC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of the rename field without changing the source code of nautilus and recompiling.

Alternatively, you could consider enlarging your overall system font somewhat. This immediately will have a significant impact on overall readability of the user interface.

Install "Gnome Tweaks" if you do not already have it. On the "Fonts" tab, you can enlarge the scaling factor from 1 to for example 1.1 or 1.2, whatever suits you best. Fonts everywhere, including in the rename dialog, will be enlarged by this.